# Launch SRT stream via Larix Player automatically on boot

Tags: applications, automation, media-player, video-streaming, auto-start

Is it possible somehow to open an SRT stream in the Larix Player app automatically?

I'd like to use the method to be triggered via the launch on boot-up.

So far, I can only open the Larix player app automatically after booting, but have to select the saved stream and play it.

Comment: Does the app support opening the stream by sharing the URL to it? Otherwise, if the app doesn't provide any API, then a possible workaround is to simulate touch from the automation app. Probably not really reliable, but not sure if there's another way or not.

Comment: thanks Andrew just thought about this yesterday as well and wondering how best to test it manually? save the URL in a .m3u file or something else(?) and from a file manager use open with to select the larix player?